# How should I cite a microfiche source at The (UK) National Archives?

Tags: sources, citation

In my research, I have consulted the "Women's Land Army: Index to Service Records of the Second World War" held on microfiche at The (UK) National Archives (MAF421), as described [here](http://discovery.nationalarchives.gov.uk/SearchUI/Details?uri=C15627).

Consulting Shown Mills' [*Evidence Explained*](https://www.evidenceexplained.com/) there are 2 possible 'models' I could use as the basis for constructing the citation:

- Fiched manuscript (Preservation Copy)

> Many manuscript materials are microfilmed or microfiched for preservation purposes only. They are not sold to the public and are not considered publications. Copies typically exist only at the library or archives that created the film.

- National Government Records (Image copies)

The guidance from Shown Mills in this case is less clear cut, as it is predominantly about microfilmed copies of US Records held by US National Archives and National Archives and Records Administration; however, it ought to be possible to extrapolate to the UK situation. The recommended approach seem to be to cite the microfiche as if it were a publication (but quite frankly, this section of the book is as clear as mud to me, hence the question).

Which model should I choose as the basis for my citation?

Quotations are from *Evidence Explained, 2007*.

Comment: It would be helpful if you quoted the two EE models you mentioned, as not everyone will have the reference to hand

Comment: @SueAdams, I'm not sure about the copyright implications of doing so. Will add a description of the two models.

Comment: If nothing else helps, you may be better trying the forums on the Evidence Explained web-site on https://www.evidenceexplained.com/forums/evidence-explained 
I did once throw caution to the winds and try to help out on an 1851 census discussion and I think the exchange was profitable to all. Not sure if "EE" is ESM herself or whoever looks after the site for her...
At least there shouldn't be any copyright issues there!

Comment: I'll e-mail her and ask what she (Elizabeth) thinks. : } nothing better than getting it from her. If she replies I'll post her answer.

Comment: @AdrianB38 I did consider asking there but wanted to try here first.

Comment: Welcome, Elizabeth Shown Mills replied this morning. Her response, Would you post your query in the Citation Issues Forum at www.EvidenceExplained.com? If you have a link to the online catalog description of the fiche at TNA, it would help. http://www.evidenceexplained.com/

Comment: Elizabeth does maintain the forum and will answer questions on the forum. She further added that citation issues can be difficult, and would be best for forum so others may benefit.

Comment: @EzriJ.Rediker, OK, I've asked over there. Seems a bit like admitting defeat here, though, and I'm not sure of the propriety of reproducing the eventual answer here...

Comment: I agree, I would've loved to had her answer here. I personally will answer it but probably not as well as she will. : }

Answer (score 3):

Microfiche series: MAF 421, "Ministry of Food: Women's Land Army: Index to Service Records of the Second World War 1939-1948." Original records held at, The National Archives (United Kingdom) in Kew, Richmond, Surrey, TW9 4DU.

National Government Records (Image copies) seem to work for me, I would use that model.
I suppose that it all depends on what you can do with the photocopy that they send you. If you're authorized to use the image then it becomes a publication.

Comment: Which model did you choose?

Comment: Image copies seem to be the best fit for me. The reason I give is due to the limited availability (it's possible to recieve a photocopy) of the index.